# Textview and TableRow Weights Not Working Properly Android

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

For the life of me I cannot figure out why my text is ending up like this. I am new to java/android programming, so I apologize if the answer doesn't seem obvious to me. I have a `tablelayout` with one static row and the rest dynamically programmed in. The static row looks fine, but my dynamic row have the 1st `textview` squished even though weight is set to 1 for both `textviews`. Can someone please enlighten me as to what I am doing/not doing?

XML:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/alchemist_favored_class">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Race"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bonus"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="2dp" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Java:

```
//Populate Favored Class Options Table
    TableLayout tableFC = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.alchemist_favored_class);
    String[] fcr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alchemist_favored_class_race);
    String[] fcd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alchemist_favored_class_detail);

    TableRow.LayoutParams lp1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

    for (int i = 0; i < fcr.length; i++){

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tvFCR = new TextView(this);
        TextView tvFCD = new TextView(this);

        tr.addView(tvFCR);
        tvFCR.setText(fcr[i]);
        tvFCR.setSingleLine(true);
        tvFCR.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
        tvFCR.setLayoutParams(lp1);

        tr.addView(tvFCD);
        tvFCD.setText(fcd[i]);
        tvFCD.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
        tvFCD.setLayoutParams(lp2);

        //Add background color to every other row.
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
        }

        tableFC.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    }
```

Result:

[Imgur](http://imgur.com/5zZT3Pe)

Comment: Why you don't use a 'ListView' with a custom row view? Would be much easier than what you are doing...

Comment: The parent view us a scroll view. Wouldn't a list view inside a scroll view be weird with both scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this --

```
tableFC.setStretchAllColumns(true);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did not solve the issue. Still has same result as in picture.

Comment: Is it possible to create the one single `TableLayout` through XML and then add `TableRow` through XML/dynamically, instead of two different `TableLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the weight from the first textview in the row fixed the issue and now displays as desired.

[Image](http://imgur.com/2H8cbbC)